# Lower bound on rank of matrix with respect to eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

I explored quite a few online resources and math StackExchange questions too.
I know that in general, rank is not equal to the number of non-zero eigenvalues.
But I was confused by seeing this [Solution to Problem 21.1 a](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.8sol.pdf). Here they seem to conclude rank based on the theorem "Eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent"
Also, the column space of the matrix contains all the non-zero eigen vectors.

So, I was wondering if I can make a statement as

> Rank >= number of non-zero(counted without repetitions) eigenvalues

or should/can it be

> Rank >= number of distinct non-zero eigen values

I could not create any counterexample which disproves this statement. Nor could I analytically prove it is correct.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$,
$$\dim R(A) = n - \dim N(A) \geq n - \dim GE(A, 0),$$
where
$$GE(A, \lambda) = \{x \in \mathbb{C}^n : (A - \lambda I)^k x = 0 \text{ for some } k \geq 0\}.$$
It is well known that $\dim GE(A, \lambda)$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in the characteristic polynomial $K_A(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$ of $A$ (see chapter 2 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/linalg.pdf).

Thus Rank $\geq$ number of nonzero eigenvalues counted with multiplicities as roots of $K_A$.

Edit: $K_A(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$ is a complex polynomial of degree $n$. By the Fundamental theorem of algebra, $K_A$ can be factored as
$$K_A = (\lambda - \lambda_1)^{d_1}(\lambda - \lambda_2)^{d_2}\dots(\lambda - \lambda_K)^{d_K}.$$
$d_j$ is called the multiplicity of the root $\lambda_j$.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you elaborate with a simple example. What do you exactly mean by saying "counted with multiplicities as roots of KA". Sorry if this is too trivial. I am a beginner in LA.

Comment: I think I earlier forgot to tag you.

Comment: @agr I added what multiplicity of a root of a polynomial means.

Comment: Did you mean algebraic multiplicity or geometric multiplicity. Did you mean that say, eigen values are 1,1,2. Then rank >=2 or did you mean the geometric multiplicity counted per eigen value

Comment: @agr I mean the multiplicity of the eigenvalue as a root in $K_A$. This is called the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue.